# How to Set Up Side Navigation Menu HTML Element on Standard Page

Tags: javascript, html, sidebar, weebly

I am having trouble getting my HTML custom embed sidebar navigation menu to close on my Weebly page. I built it in Dreamweaver and it is working perfectly fine when viewing on their or view the HTML element itself. Even on the Weebly standard page, I can click on the icon to open the menu and it fleshes out perfectly. However, I can't close the menu (unless I refresh the page).

Any help or advice on how to make this possible would be great! I want to be able to add this element smoothly to each of my standard pages.

I am very new to code and understand that this probably should have been built before adding content to the pages but it would be awesome if I could just get the last function "closeNav" to work!

URL: https://tnucii.weebly.com/new-page.html

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Blackboard Communication Tools for Students</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Raleyway", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.sidenavmenu { color: #252525;
}
    .sidenavmenu:hover {
        opacity: .5;
}
</style>
    
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a></a>
  <a href="#">Our Team</a>
  <a href="#">Blackboard Learn Resources</a>
     <ul>
  <li> <a href="#">Faculty Resources</a></li>
          <ul>
             <li> <a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Coruse Content Management</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Grades and Feedback</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Communicaiton</a></li>
         </ul>
  <li> <a href="#">Student Resources</a></li>
         <ul>
             <li> <a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>           
             <li> <a href="#">Communicaiton</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Coruse Content</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Grades and Feedback</a></li>
         </ul>
  </ul>
  <a href="#">Accessibility Resources</a>
     <ul>
  <li> <a href="#">Faculty Resources</a></li>
          <ul>
             <li> <a href="#">Blacbkoard Ally</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Accessible Design</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Captioning</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#">Accessbile Live Sessions</a></li>
         </ul>
  <li> <a href="#">Student Resources</a></li>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Blacbkoard Ally</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Captioning</a></li>
         </ul>
  </ul>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
 <span class="sidenavmenu" style="font-size:13px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Knowledge Base Navigation </span>
    <p></p> 

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "350px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change it to 1 ;-)

Your navigation is above your sidebar.

Comment: Thanks I will try that and report back